# React Router Dynamic component on parameter change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to separate my links by using one link with parameter for multiple links.

For example:

**instead of.**

User/login
User/Profile
User/home

**I'm trying to use.**

User/:id

When someone click on the User/login link the login component will be selected.

If someone click on the User/Profile link the Profile component will be selected.

I got it to work, but react router seem to be firing twice for each click.

**Router**

```
const AppRouter = (props) => (

    <BrowserRouter >
        <div className={`site-grid-container ${props.siteBgBodyColor}`}>
            <div className='site-grid-nav-body'>
                <NavigationBar />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact={true} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />

                    <Route path="/user/:id" component={User} />

                    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

**Select User Component Function**

```
const UserViews= ({ match }) => {
    console.log('-------  called twice -----')
    const id = match.params.id;
    const SelectedView = getSelectedView(id);

    return (
            <SelectedView />
    );
}

export default UserViews;
```

**Get Selected View**

```
const getSelectedView= (id) => {

    switch (id) {
        case "login":
            return Login;
        case "profile":
            return Profile;
        case "home":
            return Home;
        default:
            return PageNotFound;
    }
}
```

The code above works, but react router seem to be firing twice for each click.
Is there a correct way to do what i'm trying to do?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you make an example? I've made an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6y44p256kw) and it only fires once.

Comment: I tried it in the Sandbox and it seems to be only firing once.  Let me clean up my code to see if there is something else that is causing it to fire twice. [test link](https://codesandbox.io/s/2pp77pxzpp) , thanks.

Comment: I think i found the problem.  I'm changing the page color with redux using componentDidMount, and it seems that redux is causing it to update a second time.  I will need to look into it.